# $\{x\in A: x\not\in x\}$ is not a member of $A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

> For any set $A$, the set $r(A):=\{x\in A: x\not\in x\}$ is not a member of $A$. It follows that the collection of all sets in not a set.

The proof goes like this. By the separation axiom, $r(A)$ is a set. If $r(A)\in A$ then $r(A)\in r(A) \iff r(A)\not\in r(A)$, which is absurd.

Why do we need to know that $r(A)$ is a set? And how does it follow that the collection of all sets is not a set?

Comment: You said yourself why $r(A)$ is a set. 'By the separation axiom', which I am more familiar with the name axiom of specification. If there were a set containing all sets, then let $A$ be such a set. By the theorem $r(A)$ would also be a set, which is not contained in $A$, but $A$ is supposed to contain all sets.

Comment: The last part follows because if such a collection were the set $A$ this method would construct a set not in $A$, defying its definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you want to know it is a set is, at least in part, so that you can prove that there is no set of all sets. If all you knew was “Given a set $A$, there is an object $X_A$ (which depends on $A$, which may or may not be a set, and that is not an element of $A$”, you would not be able to do the following argument.

(Also, in some theories, such as ZF or ZFC, the theory can *only* talk about sets; you cannot speak about other types of objects; this is not the case in other theories, such as GBN, where the primitive objects are *classes*, and sets are special types of classes; or set theories with *ur-elements*, where there are some objects which can be elements of sets, but are not themselves sets).

Now, why does this argument show that there is no “set of all sets”? Look carefully at what you’ve proven: you’ve proven that for every set $A$, there exists a **set** $X_A$, which depends on $A$, such that $X_A\notin A$. Formally,
$$\forall A\bigl(A\text{ is a set}\rightarrow \exists X_A(X_A\text{ is a set, and }X_A\notin A)\bigr)\tag{$\star$}$$

What would be a “set of all sets”? If would be a set $C$ such that for every $X$, if $X$ is a set then $X\in C$. That is:
$$\exists C\Bigl(C\text{ is a set}\text{ and }\bigl(\forall X(X\text{ is a set}\rightarrow X\in C)\bigr)\Bigr).$$
This is *precisely* the negation of $(\star)$. Hence, since $(\star)$ has been proven, this statement is false. Thus, there is no “set of all sets”.

Comment: It's good to "see" you again, Arturo!

Answer (score 1):

Well, in order to talk about an object set-theoretically, we have to know it is a set, don't we?

This Claim is essentially a set-up for [Russell's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox). If there were a set of all sets, say $U,$ then by Separation, we would have that $r(U)$ is a set, but by the Claim, this would lead to a contradiction. Thus, there is no set of all sets.